# Make BottomSheetDialog Open on Swipe Up and on any touch movement

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I want to make BottomSheetDialog open when I touch anywhere on screen or just swipe up,  and want to close it when touched anywhere on screen by the user or just swiped down. I am doing it with onTouchEvent Method, but unable to do so.

My code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button btn1;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          /*  float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();*/

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    BottomSheet bottom= new BottomSheet();
                    bottom.dismiss();
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    BottomSheet bottoms= new BottomSheet();
                    bottoms.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottoms.getTag());
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }


            return true;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btn1= findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   /* BottomSheet bottom= new BottomSheet();
                    bottom.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottom.getTag());*/
                }
            });



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GestureDetector library to do it Below code shows how to use it. More info you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html). Use onFling method to detect swipe and onSingletap method to detect touch

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
            GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
            GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
        // listener.
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: then how can i open bottomsheet while swiping up?

Answer (score 0):

This particular feature can be achieved without the GestureDetector as well, clicking on the part of the screen where there is no view or swiping up

for kotlin

```
 override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
//calling your bottomSheetDialog
        newInstance().show(supportFragmentManager, "")
    return true
}
```